# Discord bot doesn't recognise avatar extension correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a script that, when a user updates their profile, sends their new avatar to a channel based on the image extension. It's working when the extension is `.png`, but when it's `.gif` it sends it in the same channel where it sends the `.png`s. My code is below:

Versao Pt
fiz um script pra quando um usuario alterar seu avatar o bot enviar ele em um canal, ta funcionando mas quando é .png o bot envia certinho, mas qunado é .gif ele envia no canal do .png e na mesma embed.

```js
client.on('userUpdate', (oldUser, newUser) => {
    const oldAvatarURL = oldUser.displayAvatarURL({ size: 2048, dynamic: true });
    const newAvatarURL = newUser.displayAvatarURL({ size: 2048, dynamic: true });
  
    if (oldAvatarURL === newAvatarURL) return;
  
    const avatarExtension = newAvatarURL.split('.').pop();
    const canalgif = client.channels.cache.get("1076541628405272667");
    const canalicon = client.channels.cache.get("1076541589062692874");
  
//-----------------------------// GIFS //-----------------------------// 
    if (avatarExtension === 'gif') {
      const embedgif = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setImage(newAvatarURL)
        .setColor('#360d60')
        .setTitle('Teste gif');
        canalgif.send({ embeds: [embedgif] });
    } else {
//-----------------------------// Icon //-----------------------------// 
const embedicon = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setImage(newAvatarURL)
        .setColor('#360d60')
        .setTitle('teste icon');
        canalicon.send({ embeds: [embedicon] });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.displayAvatarURL()` with the `size` option, it appends a query string at the end of the URL.  It means the avatar won't end with `.gif`, `.png`, `.webp` etc but with `.webp?size=2048`.

Be aware that the extension check you're using by splitting the URL won't be accurate in this case. At the moment you just split the URL by a `.` and check the last part. You can see below how it works:

```js
// ⛔️ won't work
let url = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/827997777303699467/55b85c4fe590a54c53183990b030f128.webp?size=2048`
let extension = url.split('.').pop();

console.assert(extension === 'webp', `extension is not "webp", but "${extension}"`);
```

Instead of removing the `size` option and ending up with the default size of 128px, you could update the way you grab the extension. One approach is to split the URL by the period character (`.`), then take the first part of the resulting array and split it again by the question mark character (`?`). This will give you the file extension without the query string at the end.

```js
// ✅ works as expected
let url1 = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/827997777303699467/55b85c4fe590a54c53183990b030f128.webp?size=2048`;
let url2 = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/827997777303699467/55b85c4fe590a54c53183990b030f128.png`;
let extension1 = url1.split('.').pop().split('?')[0];
let extension2 = url2.split('.').pop().split('?')[0];

console.log(extension1);
console.log(extension2);
```

So, the following should work as expected:

```js
client.on('userUpdate', (oldUser, newUser) => {
  const options = { size: 2048, dynamic: true };
  const oldAvatarURL = oldUser.displayAvatarURL(options);
  const newAvatarURL = newUser.displayAvatarURL(options);

  if (oldAvatarURL === newAvatarURL) return;

  const avatarExtension = newAvatarURL.split('.').pop().split('?')[0];
  const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
    .setImage(newAvatarURL)
    .setColor('#360d60');

  if (avatarExtension === 'gif') {
    const canalGif = client.channels.cache.get('1076541628405272667');
    canalGif.send({ embeds: [embed.setTitle('Teste gif')] });
  } else {
    const canalIcon = client.channels.cache.get('1076541589062692874');
    canalIcon.send({ embeds: [embed.setTitle('Teste icon')] });
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you just need to remove the `size` parameter of both `oldAvatarURL` and `newAvatarURL` variable.
Indeed, with your code, a gif will be shown as **gif?size=4096**...

Comment: Yes, but this way OP will end up with a small avatar (128px ⨉ 128px) instead of the size they wanted (1024px ⨉ 1024px).

Comment: I was just showing how to correct the error, of course if they want the site to me large, they must edit the variable that's all....

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _"they must edit the variable that's all"_

Comment: According to what I said, if they want to keep a size of 4096 they just need to edit the "avatarExtension" variable... It's that simple...

By the way, just as Zsolt have shown, I just didn't write the whole code

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand what you're trying to say though, but don't worry about it :)